# Slick - Join Table with Rows Limit

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I'm using Slick 2.1 and am doing a fairly standard JOIN. However when I try to limit the number of rows returned using "take()" I get a compile error.

Query...

```
var samples = for {
(sample, user) <- this 
      .join(users) on (_.userId === _.id) if user.id === 123
      .take(50)
  } yield (sample)
```

The compiler error...

```
type mismatch;  found   : Iterable[String]  required: scala.slick.lifted.Column[?]
```

Why can I not simply add in "take()" here?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your expression is invalid syntactically: you've inserted a for-comprehension guard statement before trying to make another call in the chain of table transformations.

```
    .join(users) on (_.userId === _.id) if user.id === 123
                                        ^ Right here
    .take(50)
```

To fix, you have one of three options:

- replace `if` with `filter`,
- or put the `if` after the `take`,
- or apply the `take` to the result of the `for` comprehension